# how to view a parse tree in a form with Java Swing?

Tags: antlr

I am building GUI app using Java Swing. I want to view a parse tree in a form ( Just like -gui option ) so as mentioned in "The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference" I have to use the TreeViewr class,
TreeViewr(List, Tree tree) 
my question is: What does the first argument in the constructor represents?

Answer (score 1):

This is the constructor signature:

```
public TreeViewer(@Nullable List<String> ruleNames, Tree tree)
```

The first argument is a list of rule names, which you can get from your parser instance like this:

```
List<String> ruleNames = Arrays.asList(parser.getRuleNames());
```

If you don't have a parser instance, then you can also get the rule names from the parser class itself. For an example parser `JavaParser`, you would do this:

```
List<String> ruleNames = Arrays.asList(JavaParser.ruleNames);
```